# The Blazor does not re-render when the component method has been invoked via helper class

Tags: c#, blazor

If to call the `display` method of the `ModalDialog` component directly from parent component, it will display:

```xml
<!-- ModalDialog.razor -->
@if (isDisplaying)
{
  <div 
    class=@($"ModalDialog--YDF { rootElementModifierCSS_Classes }")
    role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1"
  >
    <div class="ModalDialog--YDF-Body" role="document">
      
      <!-- ... -->
      
      @ChildContent
      
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

```cs
// ModalDialog.razor.cs
using YamatoDaiwa.CSharpExtensions;
using Utils;


namespace FrontEndFramework.Components.ModalDialog;


public partial class ModalDialog : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{

  /* ━━━ Parameters ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ */
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string? title { get; set; }

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required bool isInitiallyDisplaying { get; set; } = false;

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public bool noDismissingButton { get; set; } = false;
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<ModalDialog> onInitializedEventCallback { get; set; }
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  
  
  /* ━━━ State ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ */
  private bool isDisplaying = false;
  
  
  /* ━━━ Public methods ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ */
  public void display()
  {
    this.isDisplaying = true;
  }

  public void dismiss()
  {
    this.isDisplaying = false;
  }
   
  
  /* ━━━ Lifecycle hooks ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ */
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    
    base.OnInitialized();
    
    this.isDisplaying = this.isInitiallyDisplaying;
    this.onInitializedEventCallback.InvokeAsync(this);
    
  }

}
```

```xml
<!-- Parent component (razor) -->

<ModalDialog
  title=@localization.filteringModalDialog.title
  @ref=tasksFilteringModalDialog
>
  <TasksFilteringPanel />
</ModalDialog>

<button type="button" @onclick=@displayTasksFilteringModalDialog>open</button>
```

```cs
public partial class TasksManagementPageContent : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{

  private ModalDialog tasksFilteringModalDialog = null!;

  private void displayTasksFilteringModalDialog()
  {
    this.tasksFilteringModalDialog.display();
  }
  
  // ...

}
```

However, the button opening the dialog and dialog itself could be non-siblings.
To solve it, I have prepared the additional service class:

```
public class TasksFilteringModalDialogService
{
 
  protected static ModalDialog? modalDialogInstance = null;

  
  public static void initialize(ModalDialog modalDialogInstance)
  {
    TasksFilteringModalDialogService.modalDialogInstance = modalDialogInstance;
  }
  
  public static void displayModalDialog()
  {
    TasksFilteringModalDialogService.modalDialogInstance?.display();
  }

  public static void dismissModalDialog()
  {
    TasksFilteringModalDialogService.modalDialogInstance?.dismiss();
  }
  
}
```

Now, in the component using the modal dialog:

```xml
<ModalDialog
  title=@localization.filteringModalDialog.title
  onInitializedEventCallback=@TasksFilteringModalDialogService.initialize
>
  <TasksFilteringPanel />
</ModalDialog>
```

I have checked that all required methods has been invoked, but unfortunately the modal dialog does not appear. It will appear if to add `ShateHasChanged` to `ModalDialog.display()`, but it should *not* required.

Looks like I am not understanding enough good the conditions of re-rendeing in Blazor.
Please explain.

Comment: Why you say that "it should not required" ? you are calling a component method in async way. The only handled automatic rerended of blazor are after an **Event Handling** or after **Implementing lifecycle methods**. Calling a method on a compontent require the `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` call

Comment: There is a more modern way to control opening and closing a dialog using a `TaskCompletionSource`.  I can provide some source material if you want.

Comment: @soriolicomputec Thank you for the comment. "Why you say that 'it should not required'" - because it actually not required when call `display` method
directly from the parent component. "you are calling a component method in async way" - where? Is `TasksFilteringModalDialogService.modalDialogInstance?.display();`
  not the sync calling? "Event Handling or after Implementing lifecycle methods." - Would you please the provide the link with examples?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you for the comment. "I can provide some source material if you want" - Please provide, I must check it.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD just check https://www.telerik.com/blogs/blazor-basics-blazor-component-re-rendering The `TasksFilteringModalDialogService.modalDialogInstance?.display()` is a sync method, but since it can be called any time of the component life, it is an async call for the component; this is why the component can't rerender itself, but needs an explicit call.

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Blazor-Modal-Dialog-Implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call component method via @ref you must add  await InvokeAsync(ShateHasChanged) at the end of the method that you are invoking, to make render happen. It is that way because is out of render cycle (Blazor do not know if it should rerender component). I usually name these method that are invoked externally with prefix External.  InvokeAsync(ShateHasChanged) Will make your component rerender.

Comment: As long as everything happens in the UI you can omit the InvokeAsync logic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "Blazor do not know if it should rerender component" - I suppose you right, but from the viewpoint of logic, it is unobvious. If the template part depends on some fields/properties, should not it be re-rendered when the these files has been updated irrespective of how these fields changed?

Comment: As far As I remember (maybe wrong) Blazor is  callling StateHasChanged automatically 1.After lifecycle methods such as OnInitialized, OnparamtersSet etc .. 2. When user makes actions like onclick . Blazor checks if properties values used in component differs from original render and then decides if it should re-render them.  Also checking if component should rerender gets complicated when you use loops or load data from other services when building html. Blazor check mostly this 2 cases cuz its most efficient and common therefore When invoking method from @ref StatehasChanged is not raised